# Display text exactly in content editable div tag

Tags: javascript, c#, xml

I have a XML like

```
<XYZ>front0 

and</XYZ>
```

when I save text in xml it save exactly like whatever I type..but when I fetch from XML then it display in one line..
what is the problem?? any suggestion plz

**UPDATE**

```
XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
string LastModifiedByTrans = "";
string date = "";
string LastModifiedByQaed = "";
string QAed_date = "";

try
{
    foreach (var g in gp)
    {
        p.text = g.Text_xml.ToString();

        // LOAD TEXT XML
        xd.LoadXml(p.text);
        XmlNodeList txt = xd.GetElementsByTagName("Texts");
        for (int i = 0; i < txt.Count; i++)
        {
            XmlNode nd = txt.Item(i);
            if (nd.HasChildNodes)
            {
                XmlNodeList cnd = nd.ChildNodes;
                    foreach (XmlNode n in cnd)
                    {
                           cont = n.ChildNodes[0].InnerText;
```

..

by innerText I fetch XML value ..
its like
`n.ChildNodes[0].InnerText;  "front0 and \r\n\r\nsaid  can " string`
 but when I display it in div tag it shows in single line

**UPDATE**

```
public List<Room> getText(decimal Trans_ID, decimal Job_ID, string GroupName, string path)
{
    GroupData p = new GroupData();
    Room newroom = new Room();
    var room = new List<Room>();
    XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
    string LastModifiedByTrans = "";
    string date = "";
    string LastModifiedByQaed = "";
    string QAed_date = "";

    try
    {
        var gp = (from Trans_Mast in r2ge.Transcription_Master where Trans_Mast.Transcription_Id == Trans_ID && Trans_Mast.Entity_Id == Job_ID select Trans_Mast).Distinct();

        foreach (var g in gp)
        {
            p.text = g.Text_xml.ToString();

            // LOAD TEXT XML
            xd.LoadXml(p.text);
            XmlNodeList txt = xd.GetElementsByTagName("Texts");
            for (int i = 0; i < txt.Count; i++)
            {
                XmlNode nd = txt.Item(i);
                if (nd.HasChildNodes)
                {
                    XmlNodeList cnd = nd.ChildNodes;
                    if (role == "Transcriber")
                    {
                        foreach (XmlNode n in cnd)
                        {
                            if (GroupName == n.Attributes["group"].Value && n.Attributes["audio"].Value.Equals(path) && n.Attributes["role"].Value.Equals("QA"))
                            {
                                LastModifiedByQaed = n.Attributes["user"].Value;
                                if (((n.Attributes["datetime"]).Value).Length > 0)
                                {
                                    QAed_date = Convert.ToDateTime(n.Attributes["datetime"].Value).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
                                }
                                else
                                    QAed_date = "";
                            }
                        }
                        foreach (XmlNode n in cnd)
                        {
                            if (GroupName == n.Attributes["group"].Value && n.Attributes["audio"].Value.Equals(path))
                            {
                                string cont = "";
                                string contnt = "";
                                if ((n.ChildNodes).Count > 0)
                                {
                                    cont = n.ChildNodes[0].InnerText;
                                    contnt = cont.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "<br/>");
                                }
                                else
                                    cont = "blank";
                                if (((n.Attributes["datetime"]).Value).Length > 0)
                                {
                                    date = Convert.ToDateTime(n.Attributes["datetime"].Value).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
                                }
                                else
                                    date = "";


                                Text text = new Text()
                                {
                                    Content = cont,
                                    LastModifiedOn = date,
                                    LastModifiedBy = n.Attributes["user"].Value,
                                    LastModifiedBy_Qaed = LastModifiedByQaed,
                                    LastModifiedOn_Qaed = QAed_date

                                };
                                newroom.text.Add(text);
                            }
                        }
                    }                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Write("In fetch text data err", ex.Message);
        throw ex;
    }
    room.Add(newroom);
    return room;
}
```

Comment: sorry I didnot specify..working in c# mvc  @kupendra

Comment: Then check this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238002/replace-line-breaks-in-a-string-c-sharp)

Comment: @kupendra You are wrong. The question is not about lines replacing at all.

Comment: @debin How do you write your XML and read your XML? Could you, please, provide code samples?

Comment: Try this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205073/reading-xml-file-and-indenting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you read your XML? What do you mean by "fetch XML"?
There are many ways in C# to read XML contents of a file.
Please, provide a code snippet for fetching your XML file.

Here is my code snippet which loads XML data from a string (it is correct due to assuming that your file is **writing** correctly). It properly reads multiline XML element to a string.

**Update:** Oh, now I get it. I met the same problem when I was learning PHP. It was totally driving me crazy.
Then, I have found an answer: the text is actually displaying correctly. However, **HTML doesn't output line breaks**.

It means that:
You have XML:

```
<value>Hi
I am a multiline
value</value>
```

It is properly read to a string and outputed to an HTML like this:

```
<div>
  Hi
  I am a multiline
  value
</div>
```

However, in browser you will see a single line. 
Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s9d36a8n/
You can ensure if I am right by looking at the source code (Ctrl + U in most browsers).

If you want the data to be displayed on several lines, you need to place HTML line break `<br/>` in the end of every line like this:

```
<div>
  Hi<br/>
  I am a multline<br/>
  value
</div>
```

You can achieve this by executing

```
htmlWithBrs = cont.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br/>");
```

You will get something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/5vtk8ovk/

Comment: but in my case it doesnot shows as it is..it makes in single line

Comment: thanx for ur reply but I got an error after adding these lines
`cont = n.ChildNodes[0].InnerText;
   cont = cont.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br/>");`

Comment: it shows `Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The handle is invalid

Source Error: 


 An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  
`

Comment: @debin How do you this `cont`? Can you, please, post the whole controller or action code?

Comment: I am still getting text in single line.